# Is it possible to produce more than a block for a block producer at the same scheduled time?

Tags: consensus, dpos

Generally, we know that block producers follow some order to produce blocks and each block producer is scheduled to produce a block in the given scheduled time.
Say,
1st – Block_Producer-A
2nd – Block_Producer-B
.
.
.
21st – Block_Producer-U
So, here we are assuming the order of block producers to produce a block in their scheduled time.(Taken knowledge from technical paper)

Now, at a particular schedule, the scheduled block producer has to produce block.
The process that happens to produce a block is having two steps –
I.  Execution of transactions and forming a block with executed transactions.
II. Validation of executed block
In the first process, say a scheduled block producer names “Block_Producer-A” has to execute the transactions and forms a block. Now, the block is broadcasted to the network for validation. 
In the second process, remaining block producers(20) has to validate the formed block by “Block_Producer-A”. If 15 out of 21 block producers validates and agrees that block as valid, then the block which is executed by “Block_Producer-A” is attached to the chain and consensus takes place where every node identifies the new block from then.(The total process behind a block production.)

Now my question is that – 
(Assumed situation)
•   Say, a block producer(“Block_Producer-A”) is having more computational power and say “Block_Producer-A” is malicious.
•   “Block_Producer-A” wanted to produce more than one block in his scheduled time. Then is that possible to “Block_Producer-A” to produce more than one block? Say, he has executed transactions to form a first block and broadcasted into network for validation. Meanwhile he again executed transaction to form a second block and broadcasted again into network for validation. Is that possible to validators(atleast 15 out of 21 block producers) to validate both blocks and agree both blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's possible, it wouldn't matter. There's mostly more than one valid block.

Fork-db tracks all different valid reversible blocks producers agreed to. Longest Chain wins.

That's why it takes some time until a block is irreversible.